# Question on linear algebra-matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ an $n\times k$ matrix. Show that the
columns of $C=AB$ are linear combinations of the columns
of $A$. If $\alpha_1,\dotsc,\alpha_n$ are the columns of $A$
and $\gamma_1,\dotsc,\gamma_k$ are the columns of $C$,
then:
    $$\gamma_j=\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n}B_{rj}\alpha_r$$

Please help me in this problem, I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: You are nearly there but in fact $$\vec{\gamma_j}=\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n} B_{rj} \ \vec{\alpha_r}.$$  If you can show that then you are done

Answer (score 1):

The columns of $C$ are given by $C e_k$, where $e_k$ is the $k$th unit vector. (So we have $\gamma_k = C e_k$, $\alpha_r = A e_r$.)

I use $[A]_{ij}$ to mean the $i,j$ entry of $A$.

Note that with this notation, $C e_k = \sum_i [C]_{ik} e_i$ (ie, $ [C e_k]_i = [C]_{ik}$).

Hence $C e_k = AB e_k = A \sum_i [B]_{i k} e _i =\sum_i [B]_{i k} A e_i$.

So, in your notation, $\gamma_k = \sum_r [B]_{r k} \alpha_r$.